# How to get this plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have similar data like this :

```r
Dat<-read.table (text=" Class Value
    0   8
    1   10
    0   9
    2   12
    2   13
    1   10
    3   15
    2   12
    3   12
    4   17
    4   19
    1   13
    2   12
    4   10

    ", header=TRUE)
```

A= 0, B=1, C=2, D=3, E=4

I have tried to sketch my plot as follows, but I failed to plot it using `geom_line`.

[image]

The sketch is hypothetical and may not reflect the hypothetical data.
The X-axis shows a range of the values according to the groups, i.e., A, B, C, D, E. For example, in the data, E has a range from 10 and 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tongue-in-cheek, but this replicates your plot style with minimal code, and uses `geom_line`, as requested.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(within(Dat, Class <- LETTERS[Class + 1]),
       aes(Value, Class, color = Class)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 4, lineend = "round") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#ed2028", "#22b14c", "#ffaec9", "#a349a4",
                                "#c4c4c4"), guide = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(5, 10, 15, 20), limits = c(5, 20)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `geom_linerange` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Dat %>%
  mutate(Class = as.factor(Class)) %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(x_min = min(Value),
            x_max = max(Value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Class, colour = Class, group = Class)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = x_min, xmax = x_max)) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=c("A","B","C","D", "E")) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Value", y = "Class", color = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice one! I will note `geom_linerange` as an alternative to a dumbbell graph.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to throw a base R `plot()` approach in there for posterity though I see this is tagged with `ggplot`:

```
plot(Dat[,2:1], type = "n", xlim = c(5, 20), axes = FALSE, ylab = "")
sapply(unique(Dat$Class), function(x) 
  segments(x0 = min(Dat$Value[Dat$Class %in% x]), 
           x1 = max(Dat$Value[Dat$Class == x]), 
           y0 = Dat$Class[Dat$Class == x][1], col = x+1))
axis(1)
axis(2, at = unique(Dat$Class), labels = LETTERS[unique(Dat$Class)+1], las = 1)
mtext("Class", side = 2, las = 1, adj = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: It is great to use base R and upvoted

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalt)

Dat %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(min = min(Value),
            max = max(Value)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_dumbbell(aes(
    y = Class,
    x = min,
    xend = max,
    color = factor(Class)
  ), size = 1) + 
  theme_light() + 
  xlab("Value")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you,  it does not reflect my sketch. For example, Y-axis does not have A,B,C.. I think we could do it with geom_line()

Comment: @user330 Converting numbers to letters can easily be done and the solutions can be found here on SO. And no, I do not think that `geom_line()` is suitable to for the desired graph.

Comment: Yes, I know:  scale_y_discrete(limits=c("A","B","C","D", "E").  I am interested in geom_line () as  I saw it elsewhere, but I could not find it.